# How can we create immutable class object using setter instead constructor.As I want to use its setter method .Does it Possible to make immutable?

Tags: java

Creating immutable class using setter method from outside class. As I have a POJO Class Object creation may be done using setter method. How come it possible to make immutable using setter?

Comment: If it has a setter, it's not immutable.  You don't create using setters; that's what constructors are for.  This question makes no sense.

Comment: Ya, you seem to have it backwards. If it's possible to set some aspect of the object after its creation, it's not immutable.

Comment: Let's say i want to instantiate the immutable and mutable  properties after constructor call which will be first time only.Is the any restriction where immutable object properties will be set during initialization? As a POJO class i want to use setter.If so how .This question is asked in AT&T interview..

Answer (score 0):

Setters are mutators.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutator_method

I think you might be referring to a factory method?
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm

Or maybe you have some hybrid thingo going on.

People more experienced then me would have better answers.

Comment: I know setters are mutators. Infact fatcory pattern is not the answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Builder Pattern. There you have a separate builder class with a kind of setter for each field. The final `build()` eventually creates the immutable object.

```
public final class Person {

  private final String forename;
  private final String surename;
  private final int age;
  
  private Person(String forename, String surename, int age) {
    this.forename = forename;
    this.surename = surename;
    this.age = age;
  }

  public String getForename() {
    return forename;
  }

  public String getSurename() {
    return surename;
  }

  public int getAge() {
    return age;
  }
  
  public static PersonBuilder createBuilder() {
    return new PersonBuilder();
  }

  public static class PersonBuilder {
    
    private String forename;
    private String surename;
    private int age;
    
    private PersonBuilder() {
      
    }
    
    public PersonBuilder withForename(String forename) {
      this.forename = forename;
      return this;
    }
    
    public PersonBuilder withSurename(String surename) {
      this.surename = surename;
      return this;
    }
    
    public PersonBuilder withAge(int age) {
      this.age = age;
      return this;
    }
    
    public Person build() {
      return new Person(forename, surename, age);
    }
  }
```

You can then create a `Person` instance like so:

```
Person person = Person.createBuilder().withSurename("Krueger")
                        .withForename("Freddy").withAge(47).build();
```

With a builder you have the best of both worlds. The flexibility of setters (including fluent API) and immutable objects at the end.

**Edit:**

Joshua Bloch stated in Item 15: "Minimize Mutability" in his book "Effective Java":

> To make a class immutable, follow these five rules:
>
> 1. Don’t provide any methods that modify the object’s state (known as mutators).
> 2. Ensure that the class can’t be extended. [...]
> 3. Make all fields final. [...]
> 4. Make all fields private. [...]
> 5. Ensure exclusive access to any mutable components. [...]

To fulfill point 2 I added the `final` keyword to the above `Person` class.

According to this widely accepted definition of immutability a class with setters is per se not immutable because it violates point 1.

If think the intention to ask this question in an interview is to see wether the candidate is able to recognize the discrepancy in the question itself and how far goes the knowledge about immutability and the various alternatives to create instances of immutable classes (per constructor, per static factory methods, per factory classes, per builder pattern, ...).

Comment: This can persist the immutability behavior But i need to use setter of the immutable class indirectly to create the object.

Comment: @nityananda: Edited my answer hoping to be more clear about your original question.